# MySql Regex Pattern

Tags: mysql, regex

if string contains '-' then it should have -with number from 1 to 20

**Pass cases**

1. Hello
2. Hello-1
3. Hello-11
4. Hello-20

**Regex**

```
(^Hello(([\-]^[1-9]$|^0[1-9]$|^1[0-9]$|^20$)])?)
```

But If string has value

> Hello-21

it is able to match Hello and say 1 match found, How to say match whole

Comment: Try using `-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)[[:>:]]|^[^-]+$`

Comment: are you asking to match a suffix between 1 and 20 (inclusive) but not over 20?

Comment: Yes, exactly but if - is there

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew .. do you mean ^Hello-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)[[:>:]]|^[^-]+$

Comment: I do not know, do you only want to match entries that only start with `Hello-` followed with the number at the end? Then yes, [`^(Hello-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)|[^-]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mS4mR5/2)

Comment: I have given pass cases... It should be able to pass if string has Hello, but if Hell- is there it should be Hello- along with number 1 to 20

Comment: If string has `Hello` (but no `-` appears after it): `[[:<:]]Hello[[:>:]]([^-]|$)`. If there is `Hello-` + digit: `Hello-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)[[:>:]]`. Combining: `[[:<:]]Hello[[:>:]]([^-]|$)|[[:<:]]Hello-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)[[:>:]]`. Sorry, your question sounds very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to match cases where the column content ends with a dash followed by a number between one and 20, but not over 20...

```
SELECT ... WHERE COLUMN_NAME REGEXP 'hello(-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20))?$';
```

That should match cases like:

- hello
- hello-01
- hello-1
- hello-10
- hello-19
- hello-20

Comment: this is as expected, but how can I write this in if condition if string with

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, do you wish to select something different when the regex matches?

Comment: If have to compare a string if it passes the above condition

Comment: I still don't know what you are asking for. can you edit your question to show what you think you need in some kind of pseudo code? show input and output